# Understanding undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving this question from a test:

solve the equation:

$$y'''+y''-2y=5e^x+11 \sin x-3 \cos x$$

the characteristic equation is:

$k^3+k^2-2=0$

you get:

$(k-1)(k^2+2k+2)=0$

so the values of $k$ are: $k=1$,$k=-1+i$,$k=-1-i$

so the homogeneous solution is: $y_{hom}=c_1e^x+e^{-x}(c_2 \cos x+c_3 \sin x)$

the student who solved it made a guess for the soultion:

$$v=A \cos x+B \sin x+Ce^x+Dxe^x$$

I don't understand why the guess has the $Dxe^x$ part. why the solution has that part and it is not enough without it as the exponential part is "dealt" by the $Ce^x$ part?

Comment: Because $k=1$ is one of the solutions.

Comment: @KennyLau is it because there is only one real solution? is that what you mean?

Comment: Maybe he noticed that if  $f'''+f''-2f=5e^x$ and $g'''+g''-2g=11\sin x -3\cos x$ then $y=f+g$ solves the original equation.  And was lucky the the constant "$5$" wasn't some other value.....

Answer (score 1):

In general if $L$ is a linear differential operator with constant coefficients, $p$ is a polynomial, and $a$ is a constant then $L(p(x) e^{ax})=q(x) e^{ax}$ where $q$ is another polynomial. If $a$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of multiplicity $k$ then in general $q$ has a degree of $\mathrm{deg}(p)-k$, but $q$ is otherwise arbitrary. That is, given $q$ of degree $d$, there exists $p$ of degree $d+k$ such that $L(p(x) e^{ax})=q(x) e^{ax}$.

Thus if you have a case like $Ly=e^x$ and $1$ is a single root of the characteristic polynomial, then the particular solution has to be a linear polynomial times $e^x$. It can't be a constant times $e^x$ because these are just mapped to zero. In fact if you want to save yourself some calculation, you can do a little better: the particular solution can be chosen to be just $Dxe^x$ without the $Ce^x$. This is because the $Ce^x$ part is already in the homogeneous solution, so it doesn't need to be in the particular solution again.

Comment: thank you for answering, but I still don't understand. can you explain in another way? :S

Comment: @segevp You should experiment a little bit with my statement from the first paragraph. Choose some particular $L$'s, $p$'s, and $a$'s and do the derivatives to see why $q$ has the degree it has, especially when $L$ and $a$ are chosen so that $k>0$. Without some playing around like this, the rule will seem arbitrary.